# fontspec not recognizing custom bold font

Tags: fonts, fontspec, bold, xepersian, persian

I'm trying to convert a persian book written in MS Word to LaTeX (i'm using Overleaf as i'm a noob) and said book has a lot of words in bold. \textbf{} doesn't seem to be working with the custom font i've imported. The custom font has 3 styles in it (regular, outline, and bold).
I tried
`\setmainfont{B Nazanin.ttf}` and when I realized the bold isn't being recognized, I imported a bold only version of the B Nazanin font and tried `\setmainfont{B Nazanin.ttf}[BoldFont={B Nazanin Bold.ttf}]` I was able to create a command set to \Bold which would change to bold every time I would include it in the document, but I feel like that would make the source very messy (more than it already is). I also have `\settextfont[Scale=1.2]{B Nazanin.ttf}` In there and I switch it to a different font and back using the same `\settextfont` command.

Any help would be much appreciated as I don't know much about LaTeX/XeTeX and I'm struggling

Comment: Please provide a MWE so that we can help.